# Login to Google Apps by clicking a link (so I can switch between accounts)

Tags: gmail, google-apps

I'm using Google Apps for Business.

Currently I have two separate domains.

abc.com and xyz.com

Customer enquiries flow into each website separately. However, the staff who respond to enquiries are responsible for both websites.

For convenience,I have embedded each enquiry group inside my intranet.

I have two tabs, one for support@abc.com and another for support @xyz.com

However, only one group is viewable at a time, depending on whether my staff are logged in as staff@abc.com or staff@xyz.com

Ideally, I would like to change the current login session depending on which tab is clicked.

Basically, I want to be able to login to Google Apps without entering user/pass.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible unless you save the password in the browser.
Really easy if you create two separate chrome users and log into chrome in both. 
Voila.

Answer (score 0):

So yes, this is not possible. I have solved the issue by creating a third domain and routing all enquiries through there. This way our staff members only need to be logged into a single account. Not what I was hoping for, but it certainly does the job.